# Matrix multiplication inverse for encryption

Tags: math, encryption, matrix, numeric, matrix-inverse

I am trying to put together an encryption alogritm but i have stuck in the following problem and i don't even know is it supposed to be like this or not!

the problem:

I have 16 byte matrix to be multiplied by [16,16] matrix, and the result is a 16 byte matrix.

Then I should Multiply the result Matrix by the inverse, here i suppose i should get the original 16 byte matrix (according to the algorithm data sheet).

so can you please help me by telling me how can i get back the orginal matrix?

thanks for you help in advance.

regards,

Eng. Aws

Comment: Vote to close, this is not programming related. See here: http://www.intmath.com/matrices-determinants/6-matrices-linear-equations.php

Comment: I disagree.  There's math here, but it's not "just math" -- there are algorithms and techniques involved that aren't generally taught as part of your pure linear and abstract algebra courses.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to accomplish what I think you want here, but they depend on a few details.

There are a number of ways to invert a matrix (or, more generally, to solve linear systems).  Some examples are [Gaussian elimination](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianElimination.html), [Gauss-Jordan elimination](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Gauss-JordanElimination.html), and [L/U decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LUDecomposition.html).  You can use any of these to solve a general linear system `A x = b` for `x`; to get the inverse of A, you need to solve `A X = I` for matrix `X` (where `I` is the identity matrix).

The most important detail is:  what do you mean by "multiplying bytes"?  Your multiplication needs to be part of a finite field -- probably [GF(256)](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/laws/FFM.html) in your case -- or you will not be able to invert it.  In particular, this means that "multiplying" will not be regular processor-native multiplication; instead, you will either need to do some bit-fiddling, or table lookup (which tables are precomputed by said bit-fiddling).  Also, GF(256) "addition" and "subtraction" are really bitwise xor (note, this means they are identical to each other).

Another thing:  since you are using finite fields, I don't think you need to worry about pivoting.  To explain: if you were using floating point, your linear system solver would need to choose which order to perform its basic steps, in order to keep floating point errors from accumulating exponentially (you would also want to avoid actually computing the inverse matrix, in favor of using the linear system solver for each vector).  This choice of ordering is called "pivoting", and most references on linear solvers pay a lot of attention to it.

However, since finite field math is exact, you don't need to worry about that kind of instability -- you can perform the steps of your solver sequentially, and construct an exact inverse matrix.  The only thing you need to check is if your matrix is singular:  multiplying by a singular matrix loses information, so it can't be inverted, and it won't be a usable encryption matrix.

Comment: thanks for the answer, however, let me explain in more details: when i said byte matrix multiplication indeed there is a modulus 256 involved, as well as in the addition and the subtruction in which i apply the operation to the integer value of the byte in both cases. another thing to mention on the other hand, the [16,16] matrix and its inverse are already pre defined, and my problem is when i multiply my [16] matrix by the pre difiened matrix A, and then multiply the result by A inverse, the result is not the original matrix which it should be according to the data sheet.

Comment: If your matrix and its inverse are pre-defined, but they aren't working like you expect they ought to, I suspect that the problem is that you are using the wrong kind of multiplication.  Particularly, if your matrices are supposed to be used for AES, you really want GF(256) arithmetic, not your usual processor-native multiplication.

Comment: The problem with regular byte arithmetic (i.e., integers mod 256) is that it is not a field.  You need to be able to take the reciprocal of any nonzero number -- that is, for any byte `x != 0`, you need to be able to find `y` such that `x * y == 1 (mod 256)`.  But for integers mod 256, this is not the case;  for example, `2 * y` is always even, so `2` has no reciprocal.